# passing dynamic value to function angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

My code looks like:

```
   $scope.testByValue = function() {
    $scope.fChanged($scope.lists.title);
};
```

However on the page, the value for:

```
$scope.testValue = testValue;
```

Where `testValue` is actually an array, how do I pass my code so, if I do:

```
ng-click="testByValue(testValue)"
```

How do I get the value each time for the individual element?

At the moment I am getting the right HTML markup, however the value is always the last value that populates testValue

Comment: Can you  provide a  js fiddle to demonstrate your issue?

Comment: you have to provide your code so we know how much part you done at your side and where you stuck.

Comment: I can't actually loop across testValue - it's a value that comes from the server, So it's output as:

    <script type="text/javascript">
     var testValue  = "value1";
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
     var testValue  = "value2";
    </script>

Answer (score 0):

> How to get the value each time for the individual element?

If `testValue` is an array as you mentioned and you want to display individual element on each click, then you show be displaying those elements using `ng-repeat` and pass the iterator into the `testByValue()` function.

```
  <li ng-repeat="i in testValue" ng-click="testByValue(i.title)">
    {{i.id+ " -  "+i.title}}
  </li>
```

here's the [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/05hZQnQAvETKNnjknfOe?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="page in pages">
                <a  ng-click="setPageNumber(page)">{{ page }}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pavanastechie/NFNvc/211/)